# SSD not mountable

Tags: mount, ssd, ntfs

One of my pc's is a Windows10 machine with an SSD, recently the machine refused to boot. I attached the SSD  with an USB2 cable to my Ubuntu 14.04 machine and then I got the following error messages:

```
Unable to mount System-reserviert
Error mounting /dev/sdd1 at /media/newbie/System-reserviert: Command-line `mount -t "ntfs" -o "uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid,uid=1000,gid=1000" "/dev/sdd1" "/media/newbie/System-reserviert"' exited with non-zero exit status 14: The disk contains an unclean file system (0, 0).
Metadata kept in Windows cache, refused to mount.
Failed to mount '/dev/sdd1': Operation not permitted
The NTFS partition is in an unsafe state. Please resume and shutdown
Windows fully (no hibernation or fast restarting), or mount the volume
read-only with the 'ro' mount option.

Unable to mount 127 GB Volume
Error mounting /dev/sdd2 at /media/newbie/7084034984031170: Command-line `mount -t "ntfs" -o "uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid,uid=1000,gid=1000" "/dev/sdd2" "/media/newbie/7084034984031170"' exited with non-zero exit status 13: ntfs_mst_post_read_fixup_warn: magic: 0x00000000  size: 1024   usa_ofs: 0  usa_count: 65535: Invalid argument
Record 120579 has no FILE magic (0x0)
Failed to mount '/dev/sdd2': Input/output error
NTFS is either inconsistent, or there is a hardware fault, or it's a
SoftRAID/FakeRAID hardware. In the first case run chkdsk /f on Windows
then reboot into Windows twice. The usage of the /f parameter is very
important! If the device is a SoftRAID/FakeRAID then first activate
it and mount a different device under the /dev/mapper/ directory, (e.g.
/dev/mapper/nvidia_eahaabcc1). Please see the 'dmraid' documentation
for more details.
```

After these messages I tried:

```
sudo ntfsfix /dev/sdd1
Mounting volume... The disk contains an unclean file system (0, 0).
Metadata kept in Windows cache, refused to mount.
FAILED
Attempting to correct errors... 
Processing $MFT and $MFTMirr...
Reading $MFT... OK
Reading $MFTMirr... OK
Comparing $MFTMirr to $MFT... OK
Processing of $MFT and $MFTMirr completed successfully.
Setting required flags on partition... OK
Going to empty the journal ($LogFile)... OK
Failed to sync device /dev/sdd1: Input/output error
Failed to access '/dev/sdd1': No such file or directory
Error opening '/dev/sdd1': No such file or directory
Remount failed: No such file or directory
```

and then:

```
sudo ntfsfix /dev/sdd2
[sudo] password for newbie: 
Mounting volume... ntfs_mst_post_read_fixup_warn: magic: 0x00000000  size: 1024   usa_ofs: 0  usa_count: 65535: Invalid argument
Record 120579 has no FILE magic (0x0)
FAILED
Attempting to correct errors... 
Processing $MFT and $MFTMirr...
Reading $MFT... OK
Reading $MFTMirr... OK
Comparing $MFTMirr to $MFT... OK
Processing of $MFT and $MFTMirr completed successfully.
Setting required flags on partition... OK
Going to empty the journal ($LogFile)... OK
Failed to sync device /dev/sdd2: Input/output error
Failed to fsync device /dev/sdd2: Input/output error
Error reading bootsector: Input/output error
Failed to sync device /dev/sdd2: Input/output error
Remount failed: Input/output error
```

and then I ran smartctl on it:

```
sudo smartctl -a /dev/sdd
smartctl 6.2 2013-07-26 r3841 [x86_64-linux-3.13.0-100-generic] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-13, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Device Model:     SanDisk SD5SB2128G1010E
Serial Number:    122455400678
LU WWN Device Id: 5 001b44 78e7e1ce6
Firmware Version: 10.01.10
User Capacity:    128,035,676,160 bytes [128 GB]
Sector Size:      512 bytes logical/physical
Rotation Rate:    Solid State Device
Device is:        Not in smartctl database [for details use: -P showall]
ATA Version is:   ATA8-ACS T13/1699-D revision 6
SATA Version is:  SATA 3.0, 6.0 Gb/s (current: 1.5 Gb/s)
Local Time is:    Mon Mar 20 14:07:11 2017 CET
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART STATUS RETURN: incomplete response, ATA output registers missing
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED
Warning: This result is based on an Attribute check.

General SMART Values:
Offline data collection status:  (0x00) Offline data collection activity
                    was never started.
                    Auto Offline Data Collection: Disabled.
Self-test execution status:      (   0) The previous self-test routine completed
                    without error or no self-test has ever 
                    been run.
Total time to complete Offline 
data collection:        (    0) seconds.
Offline data collection
capabilities:            (0x13) SMART execute Offline immediate.
                    Auto Offline data collection on/off support.
                    Suspend Offline collection upon new
                    command.
                    No Offline surface scan supported.
                    Self-test supported.
                    No Conveyance Self-test supported.
                    No Selective Self-test supported.
SMART capabilities:            (0x0003) Saves SMART data before entering
                    power-saving mode.
                    Supports SMART auto save timer.
Error logging capability:        (0x01) Error logging supported.
                    General Purpose Logging supported.
Short self-test routine 
recommended polling time:    (   2) minutes.
Extended self-test routine
recommended polling time:    (  10) minutes.

SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 4
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x000f   100   100   ---    Pre-fail  Always       -       3
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0032   100   100   ---    Old_age   Always       -       0
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0032   253   100   ---    Old_age   Always       -       1165
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   100   100   ---    Old_age   Always       -       2284
167 Unknown_Attribute       0x0032   100   100   ---    Old_age   Always       -       21
168 Unknown_Attribute       0x0032   100   100   ---    Old_age   Always       -       577
169 Unknown_Attribute       0x0032   100   100   ---    Old_age   Always       -       120
171 Unknown_Attribute       0x0032   100   100   ---    Old_age   Always       -       0
172 Unknown_Attribute       0x0032   100   100   ---    Old_age   Always       -       0
173 Unknown_Attribute       0x0032   100   100   ---    Old_age   Always       -       51
174 Unknown_Attribute       0x0032   100   100   ---    Old_age   Always       -       184
184 End-to-End_Error        0x0032   100   100   ---    Old_age   Always       -       0
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0022   073   043   ---    Old_age   Always       -       27 (Min/Max 2/43)
212 Unknown_Attribute       0x0032   100   100   ---    Old_age   Always       -       0
230 Unknown_SSD_Attribute   0x0032   100   100   ---    Old_age   Always       -       326
232 Available_Reservd_Space 0x0033   100   100   004    Pre-fail  Always       -       100
233 Media_Wearout_Indicator 0x0032   100   100   ---    Old_age   Always       -       326
241 Total_LBAs_Written      0x0030   253   253   ---    Old_age   Offline      -       11374299312
242 Total_LBAs_Read         0x0030   253   253   ---    Old_age   Offline      -       24257492896
243 Unknown_Attribute       0x0032   100   100   ---    Old_age   Always       -       0
SMART Error Log Version: 1
No Errors Logged
SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
No self-tests have been logged.  [To run self-tests, use: smartctl -t]
Selective Self-tests/Logging not supported
```

I don't care about saving the Windows10 partition. I just want to know if the device is 'broken down' or if it can be reformatted and used again,

Comment: The linux tools for repairing Windows file systems are not the best. If possible, connect the drive to a computer running Windows, and use Windows tools. the GUI tool or the command line `chkdsk /f X:` where X: is the partition letter for the drive. If still no luck, yes you can use a tool to create a new partition table and file system in the SSD. Chances are good that you will succeed, but there may be a defect, that is not seen by `smartctl`.

Comment: The advice above is intended for error correction. If you don't need that partitions, go ahead and reformat. Logical errors aren't a problem for reusing a drive.

Comment: @ubfan1: OP tried to run `ntfsfix` and it resulted in an I/O error.

Answer (score -1):

You received the errors when you connected the Windows 10 drive to your Ubuntu machines because of the Windows hibernation file. `Fast startup` and `hibernation` should be disabled in Windows if you're dual-booting with Ubuntu... but it sounds like we're talking about two different machines.

The Ubuntu tools like ntfsfix really shouldn't be used. They cause more harm than good.

You didn't describe the actual Windows boot failure... blue screen, etc. In any case, if this is a Windows 10 only machine, and you can't boot Windows, you'll need to have a Windows install/repair disc to repair the problem. Running the repair tools will run a variation of `chkdsk /f c:` to repair your drive.

And yes, you could reinitialize/reformat the drive. I'd run a bad block scan or a SMART diagnostic test before you reload OS/apps/data. If it errors out, then you've got a bad SSD.

Comment: I don't think that's helpful. OP tried to run `ntfsfix` and it resulted in an I/O error, so the issue seems to lie deeper. I appreciate your effort, but that's -1 for "answer won't help".

Comment: @DavidFoerster They **may** well have a SSD failure, but since the user's question is "I don't care about saving the Windows10 partition. I just want to know if the device is 'broken down' or if it can be reformatted and used again," my last paragraph answers that. And if it errors out then, it's busted. Real simple to find out.

Comment: Thanks everybody for the advice I received, as I do not have a running W10 at this moment could not try the W10 repair actions. Testing the drive with testdisk did not work either, so I finally tried: newbie@Medio:~$ sudo dd if=/dev/urandom of=/dev/sdd [sudo] password for newbie: dd: writing to ‘/dev/sdd’: Input/output error 38201+0 records in 38200+0 records out 19558400 bytes (20 MB) copied, 8,04488 s, 2,4 MB/s.     So the SSD is actually broken down and I'll get another one. I want to close this question now but I don't know how to do that